# What's the issue in accessing variable value in smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm assigning a value to smarty template from PHP file. My code snippet from PHP file is as follows :

```
<?php  
  require_once("includes/public-application-header.php");

  ob_start();
  prepare_request();
  $request = empty( $_GET ) ? $_POST : $_GET ;
  $op = $request['op'];
  $objTeacherDetails = new TeacherDetails();
  $teacher_id = $_GET['teacher_id'];
  $teacher_classes = $objTeacherDetails->GetAllClassesByTeacherId($teacher_id);
    $smarty->assign('teacher_classes', $teacher_classes);
  $file_to_show = "teacher-details.tpl";

switch( $op ) {
    case "get_assigned_subject_list":
        $objClassSubjects = new ClassSubjects();
        $objSubjects = new Subjects();
        $class_id  = $request['class_id'];
        $all_subjects = $objSubjects->GetAllSubjects();
        $subject_details = $objClassSubjects-> GetClassSubjectDetailsById($class_id);

        $smarty->assign('all_subjects', $all_subjects);
        $smarty->assign('subject_details', $subject_details);
        $smarty->assign('teacher_id', $teacher_id); 
        $smarty->display("assigned-subject-list.tpl");

        die();
        break;
?>
```

My issue is I can't access the value of `$teacher_id` in smarty template. My code of smarty template is as follows:

```
<input type="text" value="{$teacher_id}" name="tid">
```

But I'm getting the text field blank. Can anyone help me out to resolve this minor issue? Thanks in Advance

Comment: check if it is falling in the `switch case`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you assigned `$smarty` somewhere?

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
```

Edit:

The problem was the `$_GET['teacher_id']` was not being passed from one page call to the next.

Comment: Yes I've. Unless the tpl files shouldn't be displayed. They are displaying finely

Comment: You assign `$file_to_show = "teacher-details.tpl";` but then use `$smarty->display("assigned-subject-list.tpl");` to display. What is the template you want to use?

Comment: The file I'm going to display is $smarty->display("assigned-subject-list.tpl");

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$smarty->assign('teacher_id', $teacher_id);` with `$smarty->assign('teacher_id', '1234');` to test?

Comment: I tried your trick, it's working. But how should I assign the teacher_id?

Comment: The problem is with `$teacher_id = $_GET['teacher_id'];` then. How do you get to this page. E.g. is the form 'get' or 'post'?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30501/discussion-between-james-birkett-and-phplover)